# How can I make a sticky footer in just one of two columns?

Tags: html, css

I have two bootstrap columns, and I need to implement a footer in just one of them.

I have it implemented here:

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}
.container {
  
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
  
}
.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col col-3">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-8">2 of 2</div>
        <div class="col col-4">2 of 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <footer class="position-fixed border w-100 footer">STICKY FOOTER</footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is that the position: fixed makes the footer out of the flow of the container, and it takes the complete width of the page. Is there a way to make the footer end where the column ends?

Or is there a better way to do this with flexbox?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't this approach be better? https://jsfiddle.net/mj1no4h0/

Comment: @HaldenCollier for what i have undestood, he wants the footer at the bottom of the page, but in the position and with a width as the col-9

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification @AlbertoSinigaglia Here's the fix: https://jsfiddle.net/rke9ug5v/1/

Comment: @haldenCollier as AlbertoSinigaglia said, I need it just in the col-9

Comment: Oh wait, you need it ***in*** the `col-9`, not at the bottom of the page?

Comment: @haldenCollier thanks for the help, but I need it just like in my fiddle, but not overflowing in the right. I need it just for that col-9

Comment: @HaldenCollier Please can you post _answers_ in an actual answer. Comments are not the place for them

Comment: @Martin I understand, but I would rather check and see if my answer is close to what they're looking for, otherwise it would just get downvoted. Once I'm sure that the answer I've sent is what they want, I write out a more thorough answer.

Comment: yes @haldenCollier I need the footer in the col-9, sticked to the bottom of the page

Comment: How's this: https://jsfiddle.net/rke9ug5v/4/

Comment: @haldencollier it's not really aligned with the column at the right, but it looks better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.main {
  height: 200vh;
}
.col {
  background-color: #CCC;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.black-border {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-width: 1px 0px 1px 1px;
}
.black-border:last-child {
  border-width: 1px;
}
.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container main">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col col-3 black-border">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col col-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-8 black-border">2 of 2</div>
        <div class="col col-4 black-border">2 of 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="position-fixed w-100 footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
      <div class="col col-9 black-border">
        <div class="w-100">STICKY FOOTER</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```